# how to fetch from firebase using golang

Tags: go, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database structure
I want to retrieve all the data stored in this database using Golang

```
{
    "-KaMY9JKmgyRWVApfcXW": {
        "EmailId": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "FirstName": "abc",
        "LastName": "xyz",
        "UserType": "user"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v := map[string]YourStruct{}
err := dB.Child("YourChild").Value(&v)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("%s\n", v)
```

Where `YourStruct{}` is the struct which you use for fetching values. `YourChild` is the child name of your above code.